# Spinner as one of the items for a child of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-spinner

There is a expandable List View with Spinner as one of the items for each Child.
The issue is the content of parent getting affected on select of item from the spinner. And also on selection of item from any spinner IS affecting the selected items of other spinners of all the groups.

Along with Spinner there are TextView, EditText, CheckBox. Behavior of all the views except Spinner is appropriate as expected.

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
SessionManager session;
SharedPreferences sp;
Editor edit;
private Activity context;
ArrayList<String> checkListValues;
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;
CoveragesChildItemModel childCoverageModel;
// private List<String> array_parent_labels;
String parentNameValue;
String spin_edit_value;
ArrayList<String> parentName;

// public CoverageChildFinalValuesModel childValues;
public CoverageParentModel parentValues;
ArrayList<CoverageChildFinalValuesModel> coverage_child_list;
ArrayList<CoverageParentModel> coverage_parent_list;

private static final int[] EMPTY_STATE_SET = {};
private static final int[] GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET = { android.R.attr.state_expanded };
private static final int[][] GROUP_STATE_SETS = { EMPTY_STATE_SET, // 0
        GROUP_EXPANDED_STATE_SET // 1
};

public ExpandListAdapter(Activity context,
        ArrayList<CoverageParentModel> coverage_parent_list) {
    this.context = context;
    this.coverage_parent_list = coverage_parent_list;
}



public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    CoverageParentModel parent_cov_model = coverage_parent_list
            .get(groupPosition);
    ArrayList<CoveragesChildItemModel> child_cov_list = parent_cov_model
            .getChildValues();
    return child_cov_list.get(childPosition);
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

public ArrayList<CoverageParentModel> getWholeCovergaes() {
    return coverage_parent_list;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView quickquote_child_cov_name;
    EditText quickquote_child_cov_edittext;
    Spinner quickquote_child_cov_spinner;
    CheckBox quickquote_child_cov_checkbox;
}

public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    childCoverageModel = (CoveragesChildItemModel) getChild(groupPosition,
            childPosition);

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quickquoteoptions_child,parent,
                false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.quickquote_child_cov_checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.quickquote_child_cov_checkbox);

    holder.quickquote_child_cov_name = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.quickquote_child_cov_name);
    holder.quickquote_child_cov_edittext = (EditText) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.quickquote_child_cov_edittext);
    holder.quickquote_child_cov_spinner = (Spinner) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.quickquote_child_cov_spinner);

    final String s = childCoverageModel.getDisplay_name();

    parentValues = new CoverageParentModel();

    // childValues = new CoverageChildFinalValuesModel();

    holder.quickquote_child_cov_name.setText(childCoverageModel.getDisplay_name());

    holder.quickquote_child_cov_checkbox
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                CoveragesChildItemModel childCoverageModelTemp = coverage_parent_list
                        .get(groupPosition).getChildValues()
                        .get(childPosition);

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0,
                        boolean arg1) {

                    if (holder.quickquote_child_cov_checkbox.isChecked()) {

                        coverage_parent_list.get(groupPosition)
                                .getChildValues().get(childPosition)
                                .setChecked(true);

                        if (null != childCoverageModelTemp.getLimitType()) {
                            if (childCoverageModelTemp.getLimitType()
                                    .equalsIgnoreCase(StringResource.WS_LIMIT_TYPE_INDEPENDENT)) {

                                holder.quickquote_child_cov_spinner
                                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.quickquote_child_cov_edittext
                                        .setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                if (null != childCoverageModelTemp
                                        .getLimitvalues()) {

                                    spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                            context,
                                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                            childCoverageModelTemp
                                                    .getLimitvalues());
                                    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                                    holder.quickquote_child_cov_spinner
                                            .setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
                                }

                            } else if (childCoverageModelTemp
                                    .getLimitType().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                            StringResource.WS_LIMIT_TYPE_USER_INPUT)) {
                                holder.quickquote_child_cov_edittext
                                        .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                holder.quickquote_child_cov_spinner
                                        .setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            } else {
                                holder.quickquote_child_cov_edittext
                                        .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.quickquote_child_cov_spinner
                                        .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    else {
                        coverage_parent_list.get(groupPosition)
                                .getChildValues().get(childPosition)
                                .setChecked(false);

                        holder.quickquote_child_cov_edittext
                                .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.quickquote_child_cov_spinner
                                .setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            });

    holder.quickquote_child_cov_spinner
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {



                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {

                    String quickquote_child_cov_edittext_new_value = arg0
                            .getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    coverage_parent_list
                            .get(groupPosition)
                            .getChildValues()
                            .get(childPosition)
                            .setLatestInputValue(
                                    quickquote_child_cov_edittext_new_value);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });

    holder.quickquote_child_cov_edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

            String quickquote_child_cov_edittext_new_value = arg0
                    .toString();
            coverage_parent_list
                    .get(groupPosition)
                    .getChildValues()
                    .get(childPosition)
                    .setLatestInputValue(
                            quickquote_child_cov_edittext_new_value);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    CoverageParentModel covParentModel = (CoverageParentModel) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.quickquoteoptions_group, null);
    }
    TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_label);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.explist_indicator);
    item.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    item.setText(covParentModel.getParentName());

    if (img != null) {
        ImageView indicator = (ImageView) img;
        if (getChildrenCount(groupPosition) == 0) {
            indicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            indicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            int stateSetIndex = (isExpanded ? 1 : 0);
            Drawable drawable = indicator.getDrawable();
            drawable.setState(GROUP_STATE_SETS[stateSetIndex]);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return coverage_parent_list.get(groupPosition).getChildValues().size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return coverage_parent_list.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return coverage_parent_list.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use notifyDataSetChanged() in the Event Handler of the Spinner within the Adapter class can resolve to some extent. Still searching for a absolute solution